# FFMPEG on Heroku worker dynos takes too long - runs into timeout error

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg

I am encoding a large video file that on my 5-year-old laptop runs at 7X and finishes in about 5 minutes. But with 2X worker dynos on heroku it cant even finish before the 4 hour background job time limit. I didn't have any issues until 2 days ago and now its causing lots of probelms. If I run heroku run rails console and run the job manually, I see it start at 7X but then quickly go down to 2X and then 0.5X speed. Anyone know what is causing this issue?

I'm encoding a VP8 webm file to MP4. If anyone knows a faster way to do this that might also fix this issue that would be great too!

`ffmpeg -y -i #{temp_webm_file.path} -movflags faststart -preset ultrafast #{temp_mp4_file.path}`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was Heroku throttling and they are going to remove it.